# flask redirect to authorization url

Tags: python, flask, flask-login

I wonder how to make correct redirect to authorization url. For example:

```
@app.route(rule="/add_package/<path:package_id>", methods=["POST"])
@doc_manager.doc()
@login_required
def add_package_to_list(package_id):
    return "package {p_id} added".format(p_id=package_id)

@app.route(rule="/add_data/<path:data_id>", methods=["POST"])
@doc_manager.doc()
@login_required
def add_data_to_list(data_id)
    return redirect(url_for("add_package_to_list", package_id=data_id), code=307)
```

When I try to call `add_data_to_list` method with authorization data added into request I receive 401 status code.

@davidism: you marked my questin as duplicate, but how can I use `login_manager.login_view = 'login'` in my case. I don't have method like `login`. Sorry, but marked it as duplicated doesnt' help me

My code used for authorization

```
@login_manager.request_loader
def sign_in(self, user_request):
    """
    :type user_request: Request
    :rtype: AuthenticationData
    """
    token = request.headers.get("Authorization")
    if token:
        return authentication.sign_in(
            username=user_request.authorization.get("username"),
            password=user_request.authorization.get("password")
        ).
```

Comment: is it actually redirecting to "login" page ? or 401 is coming in "add_data_to_list"

Comment: no, it's not "login" page; ```add_package_to_list``` and ```add_data_to_list``` are rather web service methods; 401 is coming in after redirecting to ```add_package_to_list```

Comment: You *need* a method like `login` is the point. What URL are you expecting people to use to authorize with? That's the `login_manager.login_view` that you need to set.

Comment: For authorization I use only ```sign_in``` method like in code above which is method decorated by ```@login_manager.request_loader```. It works perfectly (there is logic for recognized users in db login/pass). I don't need actualy login page because this is only WS. The question is how can I redirect one web service method to another which need authorization. Sorry, but example with ```login_manager.login_view``` doesn't make sense for me.

Comment: i added code with authorization method that return ```UserMixin``` object. Could anyone tell me what I doing wrong with redirect?